# Get-Service for many machines quickly

Tags: powershell

I've written this script to query the "KService" status for multiple machines. It works, but at a rate of about 100 machines every 10 minutes. Is there any way to improve the speed of this task? I have up to 1000 machines at any one time that I would like to be able to query.

```
function Query-Service
 {
     [CmdletBinding()]
     param
     (
         [Parameter()]
         [ValidateScript({ Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 })]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
         [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
     )
     foreach ($comp in $ComputerName)
     {
         $output = @{ 'ComputerName' = $comp }
         $output."Service Name" = (Get-Service -Name KService -ComputerName $comp).Name
         $output.Status = (Get-Service -Name KService -ComputerName $Comp).Status
         [PSCustomObject]$output | Select-Object "ComputerName", "Service Name", "Status"
     }
 }

Write-Host "Please select the machine list"

Function Get-FileName($InitialDirectory) {

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    #$OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv|TXT (*.txt)| *.txt"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename

    }

$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:"
$ComputerList = get-content $inputfile
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

cls

    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {

            Query-Service $Computer


            }
```

Comment: As well as this general performance improvement mentioned by @michaeldejulia, note that `Query-Service` will only return something if _all_ the systems you pass are contactable since the `ValidateScript` validation will return false overall if _any_ of the ping tests fail.  You probably want to move that into the body of the function so that you can return the valid data even when some systems are offline.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the comment based help for the command Get-Service we can see the the Computername parameter will take an array.

```
Get-Help -Full Get-Service
```

PARAMETERS -ComputerName String[] Gets the services running on the specified computers. The default is the local computer.

Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of a remote computer. To specify the local computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or localhost.

This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter of Get-Service even if your computer is not configured to run remote commands.

Try the following:

```
function Query-Service
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript( { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 })]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
    Get-Service -Name KService -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object "MachineName", "Name", "Status"
}
```